# Calculating Required Motor Power for Robot

Tags: robotics, torque

I'm building a robot that will weigh less than 75kg, and be capable of carrying people, so I need to select motors that are powerful enough to move about 166kg at a speed of 12mph, with standard 18in golf-cart wheels.

The 20s acceleration was arbitrarily chosen because it seemed reasonable.

These are my calculations:

```
200 lbs person is 91 kg.
Total Robot Weight: 75 kg + 91 kg = 166 kg

Calculate Required Torque:

12mph / 20s is 0.268224 m/s^2
0.268224 m/s^2 * 166 kg is 44.5N of Force
44.5N * 18in (Wheel Diameter) is 20.3 J (aka N*m) of Torque

Potential Motor:

ZY6812 250W24V (Razor E300 Motor)
Specs: 3350RPM No Load, 2750RPM Load, 0.9 N*m, 8.9A (15.4A Stall)

Motor Torque:

4x motors = 1000W @ 3.6 N*m of Torque total.
1:8 Gear Reduction -> 22.8 N*m Torque @ 418.75 RPM.

Motor Speed:

12mph with 18in wheels = 224 RPM Required Speed.
250W / 20.3J = 12.32 Hz = 739.2 RPM, so speed is possible with desired torque.
22.8 >= 20.3 and 418.75 >= 224, the motors can move 166 kg at 12mph or more and accelerate in 20s or less.
```

Supposedly, 4 of these 250W motors should be enough to carry the weight at twice the speed, given a 1:8 gear ratio. Are these calculations valid, or did I mess something up horribly?

Comment: You have to know the losses of your gearbox and of your drive wheels. This can easily lead to a factor of two in needed power if you use cheap components.

Comment: @BrianCarlton This site is re **ELECTRICAL**  and re **ENGINEERING**.

Comment: @Pecacheu - at a quick glance through, and I may have missed something, for F = ma, m = 166 kg, A ~= 1 m/s/s, them F <> 49.5N. There is a factor of 3.6 between. Source inobvious .

Comment: Okay, fixed. I wrote down the wrong value for the acceleration.

Comment: Also, would these calculations be the same for a brushless motor as well? Using KV*24v to get the RPM, and using the stated wattage?

Comment: Brushed or brushless makes no difference. Kv*Volts only applies at no load (rpm drops 50% at peak maximum output power). There seems to be an anomaly in your motor specs. 24V * 8.9A = 214W. 0.9N.m * 2750rpm = 259W. Overunity!

Comment: Well, it is from China.

Comment: You need to consider aerodynamic drag. Unless operation will be limited to level surfaces, you need to consider grade.

Comment: Air drag at about 6 m/s with 2 m^2  frontal effective area will be around 40 Newton. (0.6 x air_density x Cd a A x V^2).
Grade induce power = mass x m/s vertical x g Watts.

Comment: What coefficient of friction do you get on the surface you're running on? You can look up typical values. What maximum gradient? What speed do you need up that gradient?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but it may be something you want to consider when designing the kinematics of your robot. Human comfort in moving devices is often related to the jerk of the motion, that is, the derivative of the acceleration. A step change in acceleration tends to feel very "jerky". For example, elevators are often designed to have a constant-jerk kinematic profile which yields a linear acceleration, quadratic velocity and cubic position. You may want to look into the ergonomics of vehicles regarding jerk. I don't have any hard numbers on what jerk limits are acceptable.